# How do you keep track of threads/thread contexts?

Tags: c#, multithreading, f#

I have a service application, and I want each entry/dispatch to be associated with some sort of context. I've noticed though that sometimes when new threads are 'created', the system seems to be just re-using an existing thread.

When I create a new thread/task is there some unique information that I can get that signifies whether I'm on thread A or thread B (even if the CLR chooses to use the same thread)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new thread it will always create a new thread.

When you use a thread pool thread you are intentionally not creating a new thread and instead re-using one from a pool.

When you use `Task` it will, by default, use thread pool threads unless the `LongRunning` task creation/continuation option is given.

You can use `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` to get the current thread's ID, but other than for debugging/development purposes you probably shouldn't be relying on it.

Generally speaking, it shouldn't matter to your code whether a new thread is created or one is re-used.  If it does matter, it's a sign that something is wrong with your code, and you should really look closely at what you are relying on and why.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Regarding: `it shouldn't matter to your code whether a new thread is created or one is re-used`, to handle service re-entry I need to know which thread a call was made from so that I can block it until a response comes back. What is the best way to manage this?

Comment: @sircodesalot Why does the thread that sent a request need to be the one to handle the response?

Comment: Because I want to block the call until the response comes back. Is there another way of doing that?

Comment: Apparently I just needed to use thread-local storage, which I knew the whole time, just was too dumb to actually go that route. Thanks for the help!